# modprobe vboxdrv failed

Tags: drivers, apt, kernel, virtualbox, gnupg

I know I'm not the only person with this problem, but I can't seem to find anyone with the exact dmesg results as me

I have installed virtualbox and i Can't run any VMs when i try i get this error

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or >there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the >kernel module by executing
>
> '/sbin/vboxconfig'

When I run '/sbin/vboxconfig' i get

> vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
>
> vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
>
> vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
>
> vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find >out why.
>
> There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up >process, run
>    /sbin/vboxconfig
>   as root.

And My 'Dmseg' Results
>

> [    0.930689] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (2314) occurred continue selftest
>
> [    0.962022] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (2314) occurred continue selftest
>
> [    1.013351] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (2314) occurred continue selftest
>
> [    1.104676] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (2314) occurred continue selftest
>
> [    1.276034] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (2314) occurred continue selftest
>
> [    1.607374] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (2314) occurred continue selftest
>
> [    2.259142] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (2314) occurred continue selftest
>
> [    3.539692] tpm tpm0: TPM self test failed
>
> [    3.556315] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
>
> [   35.254752] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
>
> [ 2554.706121] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
>
> [ 2558.848021] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
>
> [ 2654.002179] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
>
> [ 3100.621737] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
>
> [ 3116.528224] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
>
> [ 3281.552432] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
>
> [ 3295.654752] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
>
> [ 4094.860168] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
>
> [ 4109.115186] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
>
> [ 6174.912997] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
>
> [ 6190.476835] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
>
> [ 6959.530348] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
>
> [ 6973.838775] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key

I've Honestly run into a brick wall with everything I've tried. Help is Much Apreciated

Comment: I've read often about unsigned modules, and you could search for that in AskUbuntu - I believe that the accepted fix is to turn off secure boot in BIOS.  Please see [https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/455230/82498](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/455230/82498)